# How to make a dropdown menu button navigate to a different place

Tags: html

I am trying to make a website for a class assignment and I have gotten a dropdown menu and I want to make it so when you click on a Topic it changes to info about this topic I just don't know where to put it??

Thanks!!

Comment: More insight would be better, Do you want to redirect people if so then href or do you want to change the information where the user clicks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Ethan! Please click **[edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44599734/edit)** 
your question and make sure you have a valid **[Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**, 
else, no one will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
<a class="your class" href="yournewurl">Your Text</a>
```

If you want to use dynamic functionality, i will recommend using javascript/jquery

```
window.location.href = "http://example.com/Registration/Success/";
```